# Need Help Understanding the Meaning of Certain Topics in a Writing Contest

Tags: writing

I wish to write an entry for a writing contest. The contest requires a piece of 2,000 words, and gives the following four themes or topics that I may choose to write on. But because English is not my mother tongue, I am having difficulty understanding the topics. The topics are:

> The Meaning of Me
>   Paved or Unpaved Ways
>   Because This is What Matters, and
>   The Bravest Place on Earth.

I am particularly mystified by the second one, "Paved and Unpaved Ways." Please help me by explaining what you think these topic titles mean, and what you think they are asking for.

Comment: I think that these topics are intentionally vague and intended to elicit creative responses.

Comment: What Daniel says; and 2 and 4 are not idiomatic English. Roads and streets may be paved, but rarely *ways*; perhaps the easy way and the hard way are meant (cf. Matt. 7:13-14). And we have not described places as "brave" for three hundred years.

Comment: Voting to close as POB. This OP has already asked the same question [three times](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=bravest+place+on+earth) on ELU, and they've all been closed for the same reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: As annoying as that may be, I think "What does _Paved and Unpaved Ways_ mean?" is a valid question for English learners. It's quite abstract, and I think it would be a bad precedent to close questions here when English learners get curious about abstract concepts. Close it (them?) as POB on ELU, but I think this question has its place here. "Opinion-based" would be more like: "Is this a good title for an essay contest?" or something along those lines.

Comment: @J.R.: Surely you will accept that "the paved/unpaved way" are not idiomatic usages in English. Any dictionary would allow OP to establish the *literal* meaning of "paved", and in that context it's hardly necessary for us to explain what "way" means. Nor do I think we really need to explain how "unpaved" relates to "paved", even on ELL. Anything else that might be said on the subject could just as well be arrived at by someone who knew nothing else at all about English. It's all just "creative thinking".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, I accept that _paved/unpaved way_ are not idiomatic usages. That said, I also think it's unreasonable for a non-native to know that **before** they've asked the question, which is why I think this question has a home here. Moreover, I've provided an answer – perhaps it's not a definitive answer, but it's not entirely opinion-based, either: I've included references to English literature and a dictionary link to an established idiom. In any case, you've cast your vote, I've provided my answer, now it's time for us to let the rest of the community decide this question's fate.

Comment: @J.R.: Of course. I did comment on one of the ELU that it might be better addressed on writers.SE, but I've now seen that you suggested it would be better on learners.SE anyway. Obviously I don't see why it should be okay for ELL if it's not okay for ELU - but as you say, we're both just individuals with our own perspectives. If it *does* stay open though, I think I'll probably raise the issue in meta. I can live with being in the minority, but I'd like to know in more detail *why* other people might think this type of question belongs here and not on ELU, if it comes to that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: RE: _"I don't see why it should be okay for ELL if it's not okay for ELU..."_ If everything off-topic there is also off-topic here, then I would have sided with those who were opposed to creating ELL in the first place. Instead, I was a strong proponent for ELL, because I've seen several questions I thought were deserving of closure on ELU but would be perfectly valid questions here (I can't really explain why with just 160 characters remaining, but I've prattled on enough about it in meta, and I'm sure you've read some of my harangues there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paved and Unpaved Ways? I'm reminded of [Frost's famous poem](http://www.bartleby.com/119/1.html):

> *Two roads diverged in a wood, and I –
>
>   I took the one less traveled by
>
>   And that has made all the difference*

In other words, "paved and unpaved ways" could refer to a *well-worn path* and a *way less taken*, respectively. It's metaphorical.

The *paved way* is where most people go; it's the safe way. The *unpaved way* is where the trailblazers and risk-takers go. One might think of the "unpaved way" being taken by inventers, entrepreneurs, and others who take risks and "[think outside the box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box)."

Stoney and Daniel are correct in their comments: I'm not providing a standard definition; I'm giving a possible interpretation. You won't be disqualified from this contest because your essay doesn't address the topic in the right way. I'd even guess that a unique interpretation that catches the judges by surprise might count in your favor.

As for the others:

- The word *meaning* has two meanings, so the first one could be interpreted as *The Definition of ‘Me’*, but I'm guessing most would interpret it as roughly *What Defines Me*
- *Because This is What Matters* could mean something that is important to you, or something that should be important to all of mankind
- *The Bravest Place on Earth* could refer to any geographic region whose people have shown strong mettle in the face of adversity.

Answer (score 0):

One could also use paved in a more literal sense as a metaphor for an unnatural but often-used way, compared to unpaved or natural.  One could extend that to mean a metaphor for the intellectual vs. the intuitive mind, or left and right brain, explain how metaphorical pavement is responsible for global pollution, and so on.

Oh, the thinks you can think!  -Dr. Seuss